# How to call TextChanged of TextBox WebForm Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-datetimepicker, textchanged

I use `TextBox` WebForm Control configured like a Bootstrap `Datetimepicker`.
And I need to initiate server side `TextChanged` event.
The code I have does not work so it does not call server side part.

**HTML**

```
<div class='datepicker input-group date' id='datetimepickerStart'>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" class="form-control dateField" placeholder="Fecha" required runat="server" OnTextChanged="StartDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
     <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
protected void StartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // It does not fire :(        
}
```

I try to force this event like this but no joy.

**JS**

```
$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker();

$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (event) {
       console.log(event.date);
      $('#StartDate').change(); // It does not help
      $('#StartDate').html(event.date); // It does not help             
});
```

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: your html says OnTextChanged="StartDate_TextChanged" but your server method is EndDate_TextChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add ApiController and consume via JQuery what I need.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms/

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot on the Internet I found this solution that worked to me:

```
$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (event) {
    __doPostBack('<%= Page.ClientID %>');
});
```

And on the code-behind:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent()
{
    // Do whatever, maybe call the OnTextChange method.
}
```

You can even pass some arguments in the like:

```
__doPostBack('<%= Page.ClientID %>', argument);
```

and

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string Arg){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

name of method not correct, add `autopostback= 'true'` to textbox

Comment: sorry for that. Are you using validation js library ?

Comment: No I am not using it.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the TextChanged event to fire when you leave the textbox, you have to set the TextBox control's AutoPostBack property to true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" class="form-control dateField" autopostback="true" placeholder="Fecha" required runat="server" OnTextChanged="StartDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

You also need to make sure that the name of the event handler for OnTextChanged matches the name of the method in your code (maybe this was just a typo).

Finally, I've found the TextChanged event to be a bit finicky and cause unwanted postbacks, page scrolling, loss of focus, etc., so you may want to consider using a client-side solution (eg. JQuery) instead.

Comment: If you remove the datetime picker and just type into the textbox, does it work when it loses focus?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" class="form-control dateField" placeholder="Fecha" AutoPostBack="True" required runat="server" OnTextChanged="EndDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

and it will be ok.

Comment: first let me know you want to fire startdate_textchanged or enddate_textchanged?

Comment: And the textchanged event fired when you leave this text box i.e. write some text and then press Tab or click outside the textbox any where and it will fire the event textChanged
Thanks

Comment: I changed my answer please have a look and let me know if still problem exists

Answer (score 0):

By default ASP.Net page caches all the server control changed events and executes after Postback event.
So override this default by setting Autopostback property of a control to true like below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry man, it does not work I dont know why... I found another solution. Thanks