# Datetimepicker cancels Textchanged event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

Normally I can find an answer to every question here, but this time I just can't.

The problem is when I change my asp textbox to a (bootstrap) datetimepicker the OnTextChanged event of the textbox doesn't fire at all.

I don't know the way the datetimepicker puts the text in the textbox, but somehow it doesn't trigger the textchanged event.

If anyone got an answer or an alternative way to fix this, please let me know.

My code is below:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" 
    OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" 
    PlaceHolder="&ensp;&#xf002;&ensp;Zoeken op Datum..." Height="30" 
    Width="25%"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#txtSearch').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'nl',
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        showClear: true
    });
</script>

protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowData();
}
```

Edit: I solved it by using the dp.change event of the datetimepicker itself.
By using __doPostBack() inside the event, I get kind of the same result of the textchanged event of the asp textbox.

```
$('#txtSearch').on("dp.change", function () {
    __doPostBack();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call TextChanged of TextBox WebForm Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745150/how-to-call-textchanged-of-textbox-webform-control)

Comment: Have a squiz at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12103818/34092 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707003/invoke-asp-net-textchanged-event-from-javascript-using-dopostback .

Comment: Well i did take a look at the related questions, but I thought there was an easier solution.

Comment: Did you try those approaches? Did they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatical changes do normally not fire *onchanged* events. And that is a good thing, because you would fire those events when setting values to your controls from your program, something that happens a lot when displaying data.

And your datetimepicker changes your value from your program.

Look to see if you can use the [.change or .hide events](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) of the datepicker itself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The problem is that i need to execute server side code when the text changes, so can this be accomplished using javascript/jquery?

Comment: I used the dp.change event for this now and pass the text in a hiddenfield.            
 $('#txtSearch').on("dp.change", function () {
    $('#hfSearch').html("Hallo");
});                                                                                                      Thanks for helping!